# How to add a new validation rule to mvcClientValidationMetadata?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form with two fields that need to be equal (password and password confirmation). I've created a class attribute to check that and on server side it works great. On the client side it does nothing. I need the message to appear in ValidationSummary ("Password repeated" needs to be the same as "Password").

I realized that the easiest way to check these fields would be adding the rule manually to window.mvcClientValidationMetadata. I was trying to do that but nothing worked.

My code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post}))
   { %>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <div>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)%>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)%>
        <% Html.ValidateFor(m => m.Email);%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordModel.Password)%>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordModel.Password)%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PasswordModel.Password)%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordModel.PasswordRepeated)%>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordModel.PasswordRepeated)%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PasswordModel.PasswordRepeated)%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordModel.PasswordRepeated)%>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordModel.PasswordRepeated, true)%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

`Html.EnableClientValidation` method is executed before this form is generated.

Below you'll find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst thing you may do is to execute exacly the same code - you'll overwrite the existing rules.

To add validation rules you need to put this code right after `<% } %>` closing `using(...` of your BeginForm:

```
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.mvcClientValidationMetadata[0]["Fields"].push( //check if the '0' is number corresponding to your form validation metadata
      {
          "FieldName": "PasswordModel.PasswordRepeated", // name attribute of the element
          "ReplaceValidationMessageContents": false,
          "ValidationMessageId": "PasswordModel_PasswordRepeated_validationMessage", //id of the ValidationMessageFor (if needed)
          "ValidationRules":
          [
            {
                "ErrorMessage": 'Password repeated needs to be the same as Password',
                "ValidationParameters": "#PasswordModel_Password", //'params' parameter in your validation function, can be an object
                "ValidationType": "propertiesMustMatch" //name of the validation function placed in $.validator.methods
            }
          ]
      }
    );

</script>
```

propertiesMustMatch function checks if given fields are equal (jQuery equalTo didin't work correctly in our system).

There is no "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" exception, because mvcClientValidationMetadata is generated in `<script>` element put where `<% } %>` is.